# Error de permisos con PHP en Fedora

Tags: php, fedora

Estoy trabajando con un servidor Apache (Fedora 38) y cuando quiero hacer una prueba con la base de datos tengo este error. Aclaro que no se si es problema de la base de datos

> [Mon Sep 11 10:51:22.635650 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1181:tid 1318] [client 127.0.0.1:33858] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/nube/index.php (Permission denied)', referer: http://127.0.0.1/nube/

Que hice hasta ahora?

Di permisos 777 al direcotrio html y configure el servidor con la ip 127.0.0.1

config.php

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "Pass");
    define("DB_NAME", "pruebas");
?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Ya revisaste esta respuesta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103076/proxy-fcgierror-ah01071-got-error-unable-to-open-primary-script-var-www-htm